# Cannot DELETE a record under NetBeans Debug Mode(using xDebug)

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, xdebug

When I use Netbeans to debug, the DELETION cannot be done because  **$test_affected_rows= mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)** will return -1. This is strange becuase if I just run the script, the deletion runs good. **When in Debug mode, mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) always returns -1 (it should be 1)**. What the heck is the cause?

```
require ('./mysqli_connect.php');

// Check if the form has been submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if ($_POST['sure'] == 'Yes') { // Delete the record.

        // Make the query:
        $q = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=$id LIMIT 1";     
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
                 $test_affected_rows= mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
        if ($test_affected_rows == 1) { // If it ran OK.

            // Print a message:
            echo '<p>The user has been deleted.</p>';   

        } else { // If the query did not run OK.
            echo '<p class="error">The user could not be deleted due to a system error.</p>'; // Public message.
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>'; // Debugging message.
        }

    }
```

PS.I also tried to debug in Eclipse PHP, and met the same problem. So I guess it might be a MySQL problem?